# Css floating li but not ul

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

Hi I try to float my li but not my ul

```
<form name="contactform" action="send_email.php" method="post">

        <ul>
        <li><p>Email : </p> </li>
        <li><input type="text" class="entry" name="email" size="30" id="input_email"> </li>
        <li><span id=icon_email></span></li>
        </ul>


        <ul>
        <li><p>Nom/Prénom/Pseudo : </p></li>
        <li><input type="text" class="entry" name="name" size="30" id="input_name"></li>
        <li><span id=icon_name></span></li>
        </ul>


        <ul>
        <li><p>Message : </p></li>
        <li><textarea rows="6" cols="50" class="textarea" name="body" id="input_body"></textarea> </li>
        <li><span id=icon_body></span></li>
        </ul>


        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer un email" class="button pure_bleu" id="button_send_email">

    </form>
```

so in my css I have :

```
 form ul li {
    float: left;
 }
```

So, the result is like :

[image]

SO I would like that block : li are float but not ul
Thanks

Comment: Add `form ul { clear: both; }` or `form ul { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4TzZv/2/ is this your requirement?

Comment: @davidpauljunior You're right, thanks get the result here : http://epitouille.olympe.in/contact.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/JVNPN/3/

```
form ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 24px;
    list-style: none;
}

form ul {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

But semantically you are using the wrong html elements

ul  is an Unordered List, replace it with a div

p is a paragraph replace it with a span

li is an item list

Structuring your html correctly will make things easier for you. Look at how easy it is to understand a well structured html 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/4TzZv/16/

Leo

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way also

http://jsfiddle.net/anjum121/JVNPN/1/

```
form ul li {
display:inline-block;
line-height: 24px;
vertical-align: middle;
list-style: none;}

form ul{
display:block
}
```